# How to resolve unmet dependencies: libpam-modules : PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.6)?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04, dpkg

When I try and run sudo apt-get upgrade I get the following error:

```
root@FDPM:~# sudo apt upgrade
sudo: unable to resolve host FDPM: Name or service not known
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpam-modules : PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.6)
                  Recommends: update-motd but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is preventing me from upgrading. Does anyone know how to debug?

Comment: Check your *facts* (esp. release tagged as 22.04) OR your sources, as `libpam-modules-bin | 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3        | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` is the correct *jammy* or 22.04 package; so you've tried to install something from *focal* or 20.04 thus the issue.  Your provided release is invalid; or your sources corrupted.    `libpam-modules-bin | 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.6         | focal-security` is what your message shows; ie. 20.04 and not 22.04